# TYPO3 toggle drag in wizard?

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

I have one TYPO3 10.4 installation which shows a plus at the toolbar in the module-docheader(?) and it toggles the "drag in wizard". Perhaps it's activated because this site has the GridElements extension. It doesn't work (dragging the content elements to a backend content row), except for the GridElements.

How can I get rid of it?

[image]

Comment: I can reproduce the same behaviour that it does not work. Perhaps this is related: https://gitlab.com/coderscare/gridelements/-/issues/169

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a global setting `disableDragInWizard` in the extension settings in the Install Tool

Comment: Thanks, it's indeed a setting from GridElements